# Unable to set headers in node.js in POST method

Tags: node.js, response.write

I have a case where i have to read the data from the request body and create a file and write the data into it. If the operation is successful I set the response header to 201 and add the location of file in Location header. The file creation is done using Java methods and node.js code is below.

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res)
    {
        var body = "";
        req.on("data", function(chunk)
        {
            body += chunk.toString();
        }); 

        req.on("end", function() {          
            var rtn = obj.AddonPostMethod(filepath,body);                        
            if(rtn.length < 13)
            {
                res.writeHead(201, {"Location" : rtn});
                res.end();
            }
            else
            {
                res.writeHead(400, {"Content-Type" : application/json"});
                res.write(''+rtn);
                res.end();
            }

        }); 
}});
```

The problem is that the response headers are not getting updated and are always set to the default headers 200 Ok. In addition to this the server is always busy even after the response is received.

Comment: sorry can you clarify this? var rtn = obj.AddonPostMethod(filepath,body); you seem to be leaving things out. also you dont need to chunk your boddy you can pipe it directly to the file :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're actually listening on a port with the code you reference.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req,res){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8000);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/');
```

You never declare the http object as actually listening on a port/ip with the `.listen()` function.

Also, you don't need to wait for the req object to emit anything to respond. The function is called when the request is complete. You can listen for specific requests and route them appopriately by storing the http.Server object to a variable.

```
var server = http.createServer();
server.listen(8000);

server.on('request', function(req,res){ /* do something with the request */ });
```

More documentation on the http object can be found [on the node.js documents for http](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.9/api/http.html#http.Server)

Comment: Sorry about not mentioning it but i already have a `server.listen(8080);` just after the above function. And i need my server to be up and running for all requests. Its only with POST req with body using a listener that the method is failing while it is working perfectly for GET,PUT and DELETE.